# Spring Data Solr: map type field

Tags: spring-data-solr

is it possible to define in `@SolrDocument` a field with type `Map<String, List<String>>`?
I've tried using:

```
@Indexed(name = "words", type = "string") 
var words: Map<String, List<String>>?
```

I'm setting that field as 
`val words = mapOf(Pair("1111", listOf("word1", "word2")))` but when saving to Solr this field isn't saved at all. And when this document is found by SolrRepository the value for field words is null.

What type in `@Indexed` annotation do I have to use to get Map type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer:

```
@Field("words_*")
@Dynamic
var words: Map<String, List<String>>?
```

should do the trick